# Laravel Package for Handling Image Upload and Resizing

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, laravel-6

I am new to Laravel and coming from Rails. Was looking for a recommendation for a package for Image handling in Laravel which can do the following?

> - Uploading Images
> - Validation of Images
> - Resizing versioning support
> - Amazon S3 support

Comment: You do not need any package for these things, check Laravel documentation, for image you may choose intervention package optionally.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu thank you will check it out.

Comment: This might help you in image uploading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66952341/10461328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I use for these scenarios:

**For Image uploads**

In general, you do not need any package, Laravel support this pretty well out of the box, including out of the box **Amazon S3 support**, validation, limiting to a specific file types and/or sizes, etc.
([See: Laravel - File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem))

If you need special validations and/or a drag zone, I would use Laravel file storage together with [Dropzone.js](https://www.dropzonejs.com) on the front-end.

*** For Image manipulations**

For example, for creating thumbnails, resizing images, etc.) I would use the [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) package, it is very useful and well known in the php community.

Comment: Thank you. What's the best place to place the resize code for the images? I am not sure if Controller would be the right place.

Comment: Highly dependent on what you are working on. If it's only an image upload in one place, you should be good with writing the code in the controller, or in a separate ImageController.
if it is used in a couple of places and maybe you even keep track of the images in the DB, I would create a Media Modal, that stores the image id/name/dir/path
And maybe add the creation of a thumbnail there in a method generateThumbnail that will be used in the controller.

Comment: When someone uploads an image I want to create 2-3 different sizes which we will use around the App. So it should store in S3 and then also resize and store these versions in the same folder.

Comment: Just remembered there is a good package to do image uploads & create thumbnails  and stuff  easily, I have used it in the past, It also creates a Media modal and records on media items. You should check it out as well: https://laravel-mediable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mediable.html