# Laravel image upload to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, forms, laravel-filesystem

This function is the function I use to store a new company:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   

    $file = $request->file('logo');
    $filename = 'company-logo-' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = $file->storeAs('public', $filename);
    dd($path);            

    Company::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'logo' => $request->logo,
        'website' => $request->website
    ]);

    return redirect('/company/all');
}
```

This view is the one with the form:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Create a Company</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <h3>Enter Company Information:</h3>
                        <form action="{{ route('company.store') }}" enctype="mutlipart/form-data" method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Company name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="logo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="url" name="website" placeholder="Website" value="{{ old('website') }}">
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Company</button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

This is the route:

Route::post('/add', 'CompaniesController@store')->name('store');

Well, what happens when I try to submit this form is that $file variable always returned with null:

```
Error
Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null
http://localhost:8000/company/add
```

Basically what I want to do is send the name of the image to the database and upload the image to my public folder. Neither happens with this code. when I erase the part starting from $file till dd($path); it adds the values to the database but the image hasn't been uploaded.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that "/company" in the route is a prefix I'm including with every single route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you change `enctype="multipart/form-data"` instead of `enctype="mutlipart/form-data"` in your form.
**Then put this code to your controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  if($request->hasFile('logo')) {
    $img_ext = $request->file('logo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filename = 'company-logo-' . time() . '.' . $img_ext;
    $path = $request->file('logo')->move(public_path(), $filename);//image save public folder
  }
  //You should store only filename not path in db
  Company::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'logo' => $filename, 
    'website' => $request->website
  ]);

    return redirect('/company/all');
}
```

Comment: That's not it. Please note that this condition in the IF statement is always false and $request->file('logo') returns null. If I can get it not to return null it would be solved.

Comment: Do you change `enctype="multipart/form-data"` instead of `enctype="mutlipart/form-data"` in your form?

Comment: What do you mean? You wrote two identical statements.

Comment: You write `mutlipart` but  it is wrong and it should be `multipart`

Comment: Aha. Still the nothing improves

Comment: I checked your code using dd($request->file('logo')). It works and doesn't return null.

Comment: Only this `$file->storeAs('public', $filename);`doesn't work. It return  `"public/company-logo-1597765018.jpg"` .  Use `$request->file('logo')->move(public_path(), $filename);` it works

Answer (score 1):

First of all the attribute on the form is wrong which is `enctype="mutlipart/form-data"` and it should be `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

or an alternative you can use below code according to your requirements:

```
if($request->hasFile('logo')){
        $file = $request->file('logo');
        $fileName = 'company-logo-' .time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
        Storage::put('public/'.$fileName,file_get_contents($file));
        now you can store the $filename variable in database and image will be uploaded to storage/app/public folder
    }
```

please add `use Storage` on top of file and run `php artisan storage:link` to make symbolic link between storage folder and public folder

Comment: Files are linked already, the thing is that the $request->file('logo'); returns null.

Comment: @Ali i have updated the answer please check the first 2 lines of my answer first

Comment: Checked. But that's not it

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data use this attribute because you mistype that attribute

Comment: Yeah, I meant that I checked it and got it fixed. My bad. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: what you see when you do dd($request->file('logo'))

Answer (score 0):

try changing to:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{   

    $file = $request->file('logo');
    $path = '';
    if($file) {
        $filename = 'company-logo-' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = $file->storeAs('public', $filename);
    }            

    Company::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'logo' => $path,
        'website' => $request->website
    ]);

    return redirect('/company/all');
}
```

Comment: Tried it before, it gives me no error but it doesn't upload the file to my public folder it just writes the file name for the database.

Comment: the file is not in `project_root/storage/app/public/` ?

Comment: That path you mentioned is connected to my public folder as I used the php artisan storage:link and the file won't upload to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (Input::hasFile('logo')) {
                $file = Input::file('logo');
                $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $file_name = 'company-logo-' . time() . ".{$ext}";
                $path = base_path().'/public/';
                $file->move($path , $file_name);
            }
```

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
I used this to import Input but an error keeps popping up that it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file pond. The core library is written in vanilla JavaScript and therefore can be used everywhere.  ***Visit:*** https://pqina.nl/filepond/